# What is the advantage of Gauss-Seidel's Method

Tags: linear-algebra

Gauss- Seidel's method is a technique to solve N linear equations in N unknowns, given an initial starting point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method

What are the advantages of using this method, when one can always find solutions using matrix inverse.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should never form the inverse of a matrix explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

The computation of the inverse of a matrix is often not usable, e.g if one wants to solve linear systems of equations with say a million or even a billion of unknowns, that would be a very slow operation.

Often these very huge matrices have only very few nonzero elements,
in such cases one switches the strategie for solving from exact to approximate.

A prominent algorithm is the conjugate gradient method, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method, and its preconditioned variant. One or more steps of the Gauss Seidel method are often used for the preconditioned variant of the conjugate gradient method, as a means for that preconditioning.

The Gauss Seidel method and its cousin the Jacobi method, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method are basic algorithms, for the approximate solution of linear systems of equations, and they are used as building blocks for more complicated algorithms.

Comment: But gauss seidel still needs to compute inverse of a lower triangular....

Comment: @mkuse, Definitively No!. check the wiki link in the question. For the standard Gauss Seidel method you only need $1/a_{ii}$, being a simple scalar division. Though I must admit there is e.g. a block variant, where you have to provide somehow the inverses of the diagonal blocks of your matrices.

Comment: How about case with rectangular matrices

Comment: I'm not aware of a rectangular matrix version of the Gauss Seidel method. Wouldn't that even lead to dimensional problems?

Comment: How would you even solve $Ax=b$ with a rectangular matrix? There is no such thing called inverse of a rectangular matrix. You have to somehow use a rank revealing algorithm, e.g. Gauss Jordan elimination. But this would modify a large matrix, where the iterative methods only change the vectors of the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Gauss Siedel is computationally less intensive for large 'n' and has controlled round off error.
The inverse of the singular matrix does not exist. For that case, we will use the Gauss Siedel method for solving the system of linear Equations.